# Put value of buttons into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, button

I currently have about a dozen html buttons on a page, all with a unique value attribute assigned to them.

Firstly, I want to be able to get the values of these buttons and assign them into an array. Here is my code:

```
            var myArray = [];

            $("#buttonID").each(function(){
                myArray.push($(this).attr("value"));
            });
```

This works, however only takes the value from the first button, and then ignores the rest, despite them all have the same ID. Have I done something wrong with my .each() ?

Once I have solved that, I would like to then modify the above to only add values of those buttons with ".active" classes on them. i.e a user has selected them.

Comment: There should only ever be one `#buttonID` element in the document, so using `.each()` makes no sense. If you have several similar elements then you should use classes (`.buttonID`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector represents an ID hence the `#`this why it picks only one because ID's are supposed to be unique, you need to pick them by class name like `.className` after assigning this class name to all of your buttons

have a loonk at this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you! I solved this as I refreshed the page. That also solves the active state problem too!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you decided to use a common class for your buttons instead of an ID. Example:

```
<button class="my-class".......
```

There's a wonderful jQuery method that would put the values of all the button's with this class in an array like so:

```
var myArray = $('.my-class').map(function() {
    return this.value;
})
.get();
```