# insert values of clicked buttons into array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I am trying to get the values of the first 9 clicked buttons and put them into an array named `$u_input`. I actually found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458115/put-value-of-buttons-into-array), but its in javascript.

**my html:**

```
 <div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" style="width:50%;height:40%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; float:left" class="ui-btn"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" style="width:50%;height:40%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;float:right" class="ui-btn"></button>
    </div> // I have up to 9 buttons, thats only a piece
```

**my javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-btn').click(function(){
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
        var ajaxurl = 'escreen.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        });
    });

});
```

**my php:**

```
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

$u_input = array($_POST['action'](1), $_POST['action'](2), $_POST['action'](3), $_POST['action'](4));


echo $u_input;  
}
```

Comment: Change: **`<button id="btn-1"> value-1 </button>`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the buttons with the following code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ajaxurl = 'escreen.php',
    $values = [];
    $('button').each(function(){
        $values.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            buttons: $values,
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Yay it worked');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

An even nicer way to do it would be to set a name for each property in your array:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var ajaxurl = 'escreen.php',
    $values = [];
    $('button').each(function(){
        $values[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            buttons: $values,
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('Yay it worked');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

The array `$values` should contain the following:

`[button1: "value1", button2: "value2", button3: "value3"]`

So in your PHP file you can retreive it by using:

`$_POST['buttons']['button1']`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I take the first code snippet, because I have 9 different buttons and I need only a array with numbers. :)

Comment: Ok that's fine, but then you should not us the `$_POST['buttons']['button1']`, but just `$_POST['buttons']`

Comment: How can I echo the resulting array in php? :D

Comment: You can use echo `$_POST['buttons'][0]` if i am right if you use option 1, or just do an `var_dump($_POST['buttons'])`  to see what is going on. Or do an `foreach($_POST['buttons'] as $k => $v){ var_dump($v); }`